# get status on local URL with moneybookers

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am using **Money Bookers** for the payment processing.

Is there any possibility that I can get the order status to my local URL same as paypal IPN.

I am able to set the status url like below :

```
<input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="<?php echo $cfg->webroot?>/index.php?control=add_fund&do=status">
```

But its responding only to live url but not for the local URL. So is there any way to get the order status on local URL?

Comment: When you say local url do you mean http://localhost/index.php?control=add_fund&do=status?

Answer (score 1):

Moneybookers can only send notifications to a publicly accessible site. So if you want notifications to your development machine, you need a public IP, and Moneybookers needs to able to access port 80.

You can check if your port 80 is accessible by doing a [simple online port scan](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/).

A thing to remember is that the status_url you send will be tied to that subscription until it ends, so don't test this in production.

Comment: + 1 excellent information. Spent ages trying to debug similar problem on my test server. Turns out to be a port number issue. I could not find this information anywhere. Do you mind me asking where you got it?

Comment: It's pretty obvious if you think about it, MB just sends a regular web request, which needs a public ip and the http port open. Their API documentation could be improved however.